# Override NSCollectionView item size

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, xcode7.3

So I have a collection view rendering with sections and items. I am using flowLayout and set the default item size like so:

```
flowLayout.itemSize = NSSize(width: 64.0, height: 128.0)
```

According to the documentation, "...The collection view’s delegate can override the default size values and specify different values for each item."

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the documentation,

> This property [`itemSize`] contains the default size of items. If you do not provide an estimated size or implement the `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` method in your delegate, the flow layout uses this value for the size of each item.

So you can simply implement [this delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout/collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:) to return a different size for each item if desired.

You may also wish to read about the [`estimatedItemSize` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSCollectionViewFlowLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSCollectionViewFlowLayout/estimatedItemSize).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize there was a separate page for the flow layout delegate. You also helped me when it comes to reading their documentation.

Comment: Reading Apple documentation is a very useful skill to have! You should also remember to read the actual header files like `NSCollectionViewFlowLayout.h` — these sometimes have comments with information not represented in the online documentation. In this case it looks like there isn't much, but it's usually worth looking.